# Xubuntu keeps resetting workspace count to 1

Tags: workspaces, xubuntu

I've just installed Xubuntu 11.04 on my netbook and I'm noticing a problem with the workspace setup. If I log in, I see there's only one workspace specified. If I load the 'Workspaces' control panel widget and alter it to 4, this works fine until I reboot and log in again, at which point the number of workspaces is reset to 1.

How do I get XFCE4 to remember my workstation number preference?

Comment: Have you installed compiz? Is xfsettingsd running? If compiz is installed, you must change the workspaces using ccsm.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this file:
 `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfwm4.xml`

It is where the numbers of workspaces are defined in xfce.

Comment: I'm at mobile phone right now, I will put more details ASAP ;-)

Comment: changing the workspaces value in that file doesnt take effect until you logout and login or reboot.  It will be interesting to see if the OP issue is due to something resetting that file back to its defaults.

Comment: For some reason, after having checked the permissions twice, if I explicitly set the ownership of xfwm4.xml I seem to have fixed the problem. Not sure why doing a chown on the file specifically rather than the overall directory would have a different effect, but there it is.

Comment: I'm glad it is working now ;-)

Comment: Tell a lie, it's back to not working. Oddly enough, it's just that one parameter that's being replaced, and only on login. If I set workspace names, they are persisted, but the workspace_count parameter is still being reset to 1. Is there any way I can figure out what processes are accessing that file during a certain time period?

Comment: I will try to figure out. Untill then, can you try to change the attributes of this file to immutable? 'chattr +i ~/path.to.file'. I'm on vacation very far away from home, at mobile phone only...

Comment: It does not work for me either. I'm on Manjaro with XFCE. When I edit the file, it will reset on login. And when I simply use the graphical workspace editor, I can set the number, but it won't add any new workspaces. I only ever have one workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you own the ".config/xfce4/xfconf" directory, and that you have the right permission on it:

```
sudo chown -R YOUR_USER:YOUR_GROUP .config/xfce4/xfconf

chmod -R 755 .config/xfce4/xfconf
```

Substitute YOUR_USER:YOUR_GROUP with your user and group (eg. "growse:growse")

Comment: Yes, I've got the correct ownership of that directory and all files inside it, with the correct permissions of them.